# eigenvalues of A - aI in terms of eigenvalues of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck with this question of my assignment where given that *A is nxn square matrix and a be a scalar* it is asked to -

1. Find the eigenvalues of A -  aI in terms of eigenvalues of A.
2. A and A -  aI have same eigenvectors.

I am not able to generalise the relation. Kindly help me out!

Comment: This has been asked ,many times before. Let $(\lambda, v)$ be an eigenpair of $A$ and multiply $A-aI$ on the right by $v$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding eigenvector $X$. We have
$$AX=\lambda X.$$
Consider
$$B=A-a I.$$
We have
$$BX = (A-aI)X=AX-aIX=\lambda X-aX = (\lambda - a)X.$$
Thus, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda-a$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

If c is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Av = c.v$ for the corresponding eigenvector.

This implies $(A - aI)v = (c - a)v$. Thus, if c is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $c-a$ is an eigenvalue of $A - aI$. This also shows that eigenvectors of $A$ and $A - aI$ are same.